# ResponseMetadata not provided by AWS DAX queries

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I have been using DAX on top of my DynamoDB queries.
I will write Lambda functions and test them locally.  However I can only use DAX in a VPC so as far as I can tell I cannot use DAX locally. To get around this I have a databse handler that either uses DAX or Dynamo depending on the env.  This means however that I am never using DAX during my development and have noticed that the Lambda logs show that the response from DAX is basically empty, and where I am using the expected ResponseMetadata in my code to verify the success or failure of a query.

I need to work out how to use DAX locally really but essentially I would love to know even more how to work with this lack of a response and whether I can get one out of it?  Or if I should just rely on the result of try/except.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: "Unfortunately DAX is a VPC only service, you would be unable to connect to it locally with ease. Can you share with me which ResponseMetadata you are dependent on, I can raise a feature request with the DAX team internally to expose the metadata in the response." is the response I got on the AWS forum

Answer (score 2):

> DAX would throw an exception if the response was a non 200, which you would catch in your try/catch. Allowing all_old is incase you overwrite an item and want to know its values, you already know the new values as thats what you are currently writing.
>
> In DynamoDB you will only get a 200 if the item is persisted to at least 2/3 storage nodes, which means items are always durable when you receive a 200 response.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUEruXJYA7RSynZtxkcfhPyg/dax-in-front-of-dynamo-does-not-reply-with-response-metadata

TLDR: Don't rely on ResponseMetadata, use Try/Catch (exception)